# Count item repetitions within a container

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, std

How can I count item repetitions within a container in C++?

The problem goes like this:
I have a vector with many items on it, how can I know the number of repetitions each element has?

I've seen solutions where you have to create another vector (let's call this countVector) with the value and repetitions then loop through the vector checking if the value hasn't been added to the countVector if the value has been added then proceed to increase the repetitions by 1 but if not then add the new value and set repetitions to 1.

let's be fair, this implementation is an overkill, takes two loops, one to go through the items vector and another to check if the value has been added.

is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a more efficient way to do this kind of tasks, this by using a map, more precisely a std::map.

the algorithm to do the count is:

- create a map with `map<dataDesired, int> itemRepetitions`
- loop thorugh the items vector
- increment itemRepetitions[itemInVector]

let's suppose we have a `vector<string> called items;`
to count every item repetition we only need to do the following

```
std::vector<std::string> items { "ja", "an", "di", "ja", "ja", "an", "di", "be" };    
std::map<std::string, int> itemsCount;

for (std::string item : items)
{
    ++itemsCount[item];
}

//print the map
for (auto item : itemsCount)
    std::cout << "Value: " << item.first << " repetitions: " << item.second << std::endl;
```

outputs:

```
Value: an repetitions: 2
Value: be repetitions: 1
Value: di repetitions: 2
Value: ja repetitions: 3
```

if you want this to be more "general/global" you can as always create a template function to count elements on a vector of any type

```
template <class datatype>
std::map<datatype, int> count_elements_in(std::vector<datatype> items)
{
    std::map<datatype, int> itemsCount;

    for (datatype item : items)
        ++itemsCount[item];

    return itemsCount;
}
```

this function returns a map of the type received with the values repetitions in the vector passed as parameter, the vector can be of any type. Lets try it out:

```
std::vector<std::string> itemsStr{ "ja", "an", "di", "ja", "ja", "an", "di", "be" };
std::vector<int> itemsInt{ 1, 2, 8, 4 , 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3 };
std::vector<double> itemsDouble{ 1.2, 2.1, 8.3, 4 , 1.2, 1.2, 2.1, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6 };

std::map<std::string, int> itemsCountStr = count_elements_in(itemsStr);
std::map<int, int> itemsCountInt = count_elements_in(itemsInt);
std::map<double, int> itemsCountDouble = count_elements_in(itemsDouble);
```

if we print the itemsCounts we will get the following outputs:

```
strings count:
Value: an repetitions: 2
Value: be repetitions: 1
Value: di repetitions: 2
Value: ja repetitions: 3

ints count:
Value: 1 repetitions: 3
Value: 2 repetitions: 2
Value: 3 repetitions: 3
Value: 4 repetitions: 1
Value: 8 repetitions: 1

floats count:
Value: 1.2 repetitions: 3
Value: 2.1 repetitions: 2
Value: 3.6 repetitions: 3
Value: 4 repetitions: 1
Value: 8.3 repetitions: 1
```

with this we can know how many times every item is repeated in a given container like a vector.

I made this question and answered since I noticed that in most post related to his kind of tasks, people tend to do the double loop algorithm explained before instead of using the features of the C++ language I know that this might not be the most efficient way to do this task but is way more optimized than the double loop algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Using an unordered map is more efficient for lookups. Lookups only cost O(1) with unordered maps

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> names { "one", "two", "two", "three", "three", "three"};    
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> names_map;

    for (const std::string& name : names)
    {
        ++names_map[name];
    }

    for (auto name : names_map)
    {
        std::cout << "Value: " << name.first << " repetitions: " << name.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: So good to know that there's a better implementation of std::map, I thought that std::map was hashed but it seems that I was wrong, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Actually, lookups in `std::unordered_map` can be as fast as `O(1)`. They can also be as slow as `O(N)`. Depends on the data and the hash algorithm.